# What should you do if a question already asked doesn't provide a satisfactory answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked [How are Animated Objects created?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96782) and it was suggested that it was a duplicate of [What are the rules for making constructs other than golems?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56008). I can see that they are indeed very similar but I was not happy with the answer on the original question so believe it is right to ask a separate question.

So far the answer I have received on my question does add a little information that wasn't in the original question's answers.

In a case like this is it right to ask a duplicate question?

Answer (score 7):

No, it's never OK to ask a duplicate question.  Bump the old question with an edit, consider leaving a comment, or even better, place a bounty.

If the questions are not truly duplicates, then it's fine. The questions as they are asked are duplicates.  But it sounds like your real question is about costing a manual of animate object, which would not be a duplicate.  So in this case it's possible asking about your actual problem would solve a variety of issues.

Comment: Isn't the site happy with good duplicate questions? It just won't solve his problem because it'll be closed and receive no new answers, but the practice itself isn't frowned upon I think?

Comment: You may have noticed that one of the close reasons is "duplicate..."

Comment: That doesn't automatically mean it's an issue, though.
https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Not gonna argue about it.  Here, we close obvious duplicates.  "Not quite the same" is fine. Again, in this case, an extra 20 seconds of the OP rubbing their brain cells together should result in a question about their real problem which is not a dupe.

Comment: We should definitely close them; I wasn't saying we should leave them open. Just that asking a duplicate isn't neccesarily bad. They'll be closed for sure, but they are an extra way for google to turn your question into an answer and so not "never OK to ask a duplicate question", just not a good way to obtain fresh answers because it'll be closed.

Comment: "Closed but linked" is actually a reasonably good outcome for prompting better answers when the question _really is_ the same.

Comment: About the "Bump the old question with an edit" part: which kind of edit? Can't this be seen as intrusive from the original OP?

Comment: One that improves it, and yes if done poorly.

Comment: This is what we tell people but has it ever actually worked for anyone? IME, you're pretty much SoL unless you write well enough to go instantly viral and have the 'dupe' changed to be of your question. If you have enough rep on SE to bounty something, then you probably know how to answer your own questions (or you're that guy who can write). Nobody answers bumped old questions except new people who don't know the deal with FGitW yet.